# Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) not work

Tags: linkedin-api

In my use case I need to use application authorization (2-step OAuth) to generate an access token to make authenticated API calls. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-08) I can call this url `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` with my ClientID and ClientSecret, I always have this answer

```
{
"Error: access denied",
"error_description": "This app is not allowed to create app tokens"
}
```

I also can use the [linkedin token generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/developer-portal-tools?view=li-lms-2022-08#generate-a-token-in-the-developer-portal) tool but in my case the client credential (2-legged) is not available [when trying to generate token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SbMw.png)

My question is what should i do to have the Application Authorization (2-legged) and generate tokens?

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-08) The given [link for permissions request](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) is not reachable.